# How to specify conv_filters when using a custom obs shape?

Tags: conv-neural-network, ray

I'm using a custom environment to run a Ray's `run_experiment` function.

My observation_space is

```py
spaces.Box(low=-np.finfo(np.float32).max,
           high=np.finfo(np.float32).max,
           shape=(3, 76),
           dtype=np.float16)
```

The input is an array with three arrays inside, each one containing 76 items. Something like this:

```
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0.],
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0.],
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0.]]
```

When I try to run my train script without specifying the `conv_filters` I receive this error:

```sh
ValueError: No default configuration for obs shape [3, 76], you must specify `conv_filters` manually as a model option. Default configurations are only available for inputs of shape [42, 42, K] and [84, 84, K]. You may alternatively want to use a custom model or preprocessor.
```

So I'm configuring this in my train script:

```py
"model": {
    "dim": 3,
    "conv_filters": [[3, [1, 1], 1]]
}
```

But when doing so I receive this one:

```sh
ValueError: Convolution expects input with rank 4, got 3
```

btw my input is not an image, it is actually 3 rows of a time series, each row has 76 items.

I think I'm wrong in this line `"conv_filters": [[3, [1, 1], 1]]` but idk how to fix it, so I need help...

Is there some way to not do convolution? because I don't wanna lose information here, it is a time-series, every little info worth.

- Here's my [train script](https://github.com/Draichi/cryptocurrency_algotrading/blob/master/train_multi_model.py)
- Here's the [observation](https://github.com/Draichi/cryptocurrency_algotrading/blob/d6e156a09f39d0ae5bb218928801001c1473124b/env/MultiModelEnv.py#L38)

I made a [test](https://github.com/Draichi/cryptocurrency_algotrading/blob/master/test_multimodel.py) to see if the custom env works without ray and it does.

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 3):

You can force RLlib to use a fully connected network by using a custom model option. Here's an example in code: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/examples/custom_env.py

Comment: The link is dead. Here's the new [link](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/rllib/examples/custom_env.py)